# What is the name of this jazz song used in this video at this point?

Tags: identify-this-song, jazz, swing

Video is Mike Boyd: "This Week I learnt to split apples"

https://youtu.be/aPNTutAtbSU?t=2m57s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called Shake Down by Gavin Luke.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_-uV3HzkII